# Flutter: Draw container from bottom to top using SizeTransition

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter and mobile development. I have a need to draw a Container from the bottom position to the top using SizeTransition and Animation. Here is my code. My animation is `Tween (begin: 1.0, end: 1.0)`, it draws the Container first, and then clears it from the bottom up. Instead, I want it to be drawn from the bottom up.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test1State createState() => _Test1State();
}

class _Test1State extends State<Test1> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  double topPosition = 10, leftPosition = 10;
  double height = 100;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _expandAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
    _expandAnimation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  bool showFlag = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Bar')),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizeTransition(
              axisAlignment: 1,
              sizeFactor: _expandAnimation,
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: is it ok If i draw with different way

Answer (score 0):

I implemented using Stack and white Container.
(I think that it is best way.)

1. Draw blue container
2. Cover white container(you need to set color same with background color) that has same size with blue container
3. change white Container size from bottom to up

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Test1();
  }
}

class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test1State createState() => _Test1State();
}

class _Test1State extends State<Test1> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  double topPosition = 10, leftPosition = 10;
  double height = 100;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _expandAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
    _expandAnimation =
        Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  bool showFlag = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Bar')),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            SizeTransition(
              axisAlignment: 1,
              axis: Axis.vertical,
              sizeFactor: _expandAnimation,
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```